# Respondent supplementary points from correspondence analysis using ca package in R?

Tags: r, pca, factor-analysis, correspondence-analysis

I am new to correspondence analysis and I'm trying to decipher a paper's application of it.

The authors surveyed 100 consumers on attributes that they would assign to different deodorant brands. The attributes where shown to consumers and they were to check the attributes that they thought applied to each brand. This produced an indicator (0=not checked, 1=checked) matrix for each consumer. These indicator matrices were aggregated over consumers to produce the contingency table in figure 1. They ran CA and produced the symmetric map in figure 2.

Figure 1
[image]

Figure 2
[image]

The authors then say that they mapped consumer level brand attribute assignments into the space defined in figure 2 to obtain individual level coordinates. Put another way, the individual brand attribute assignments were mapped into the space as supplementary variables and they derived coordinates from the supplementary variables.

How can one derive these supplementary coordinates using the ca package in R?
What would the matrix need to look like to do this?

Comment: I didn't fully understand you. Still I suppose that you are asking if it is possible to do a triplot. A triplot is an overlay scatterplot showing both brands and attributes and individual respondents' "scores" on the map. It is possible, in some settings - I've done such things in categorical PCA (CATPCA) in spss. Since Multiple correspospondence analysis can be seen as a specific case of CATPCA I suppose that it is possible with CA, too. But that have to be explored/tested

Comment: Hi @ttnphns, the end goal is actually just acquiring these "respondent" level coordinates.